# how to make first tab active by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using tab functionality, I want to show first tab active by default

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row quick-filters js-quick-filters">
        <a href="${allOpenOrder}" class="allOpenOrder"><spring:theme code="text.retailer.dashboard.order.all" arguments="${allOrderCount}" />&nbsp;</a>
        <a href="${acceptOrrejectOrder}" class="acceptOrrejectOrder"><spring:theme code="text.retailer.dashboard.order.accept.reject" arguments="${acceptOrrejectOrderCount}" />&nbsp;</a>
        <a href="${pickupOrder}" class="pickupOrder"><spring:theme code="text.retailer.dashboard.order.awaiting.pickup" arguments="${pickupOrderCount}" />&nbsp;</a>
        <a href="${deliveryOrder}" class="deliveryOrder"><spring:theme code="text.retailer.dashboard.order.awaiting.delivery" arguments="${deliveryOrderCount}" />&nbsp;</a>
        <a href="${paymentOrder}" class="paymentOrder"><spring:theme code="text.retailer.dashboard.order.request.payment" arguments="${paymentOrderCount}" />&nbsp;</a>
    </div>
</div>


var currentPath = location.pathname + location.search;
$('.js-quick-filters>a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('href') === currentPath) {
        $(this).addClass('activeTab');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('activeTab');
    }
});
```

First tab should be active by default

Comment: why don't you add the class directly to first anchor tag `class="allOpenOrder activeTab"`

Comment: I agree with @skdroid, this is simple way directly, then after jquery check next procedure

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentPath = location.pathname + location.search;
$('.js-quick-filters>a:eq(0)').addClass('activeTab');
$('.js-quick-filters>a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('href') === currentPath) {
        $(this).addClass('activeTab');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('activeTab');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the class to your html.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row quick-filters js-quick-filters">
        <a href="${allOpenOrder}" class="allOpenOrder activeTab"><spring:theme code="text.retailer.dashboard.order.all" arguments="${allOrderCount}" />&nbsp;</a>
        <a href="${acceptOrrejectOrder}" class="acceptOrrejectOrder"><spring:theme code="text.retailer.dashboard.order.accept.reject" arguments="${acceptOrrejectOrderCount}" />&nbsp;</a>
        <a href="${pickupOrder}" class="pickupOrder"><spring:theme code="text.retailer.dashboard.order.awaiting.pickup" arguments="${pickupOrderCount}" />&nbsp;</a>
        <a href="${deliveryOrder}" class="deliveryOrder"><spring:theme code="text.retailer.dashboard.order.awaiting.delivery" arguments="${deliveryOrderCount}" />&nbsp;</a>
        <a href="${paymentOrder}" class="paymentOrder"><spring:theme code="text.retailer.dashboard.order.request.payment" arguments="${paymentOrderCount}" />&nbsp;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will make the first tab active by default.